# Communication between NodeJS server and react

Tags: php, node.js, reactjs

I'm a beginner in NodeJS and React.

How does general communication work in React and NodeJS?
I've done it with APIs, but are there other ways?

For example in PHP my login system: The login info just gets compared to the db info, no api required . Is there anything else in nodejs for communication with react aside from APIs?

I've also heard about server side rendering? Does PHP do this?

Thannks in advance,
Kind regards!

Comment: You can treat your server-side processes as APIs, making asynchronous requests from your React app. You can also render some or all of your frontend applications server-side. These two approaches are not mutually exclusive

Comment: when you use react with nodeJS you need to use api for communicating react.If you want use rendering in nodeJS you need to use EJS modules that can help you like php.

Comment: There's no other way than APIS?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use any template engine like ejs which give you ability to work in same environment as PHP.
It's HTMl with embedded javascript.
It;s so popular and easy to use.
here is link https://ejs.co/#install
more questions about ejs, JavaScript are welcome